# Is Xがないとだめ "must have X"? And sentence-ending かね

Tags: meaning, sentence-final-particles, grammar

In an anime, two characters are talking about playing basketball and why should someone not versed in it be interested at all; one of them says:

> バスケやるのに理由がないとだめですかね

which is translated as "To be honest, I'm not sure anybody actually needs a reason to play basketball". I'm not sure if I understand the sentence, but I think in the translation there is something different from the original (like it being a question turned affirmation, if I'm right).

My breakdown is:

- バスケやるのに: in order to play basket
- 理由: reason
- がないとだめ: が particle + must have
- ですかね: です + question marker + ね particle

More literally, it's something like "Do you (really) must have a reason in order to play basket?", so "Do you really need a reason to play basket?"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「バスケやるのに理由{りゆう}がないとだめです**かね**」

Translator's TL:

> "To be honest, I'm not sure anybody actually needs a reason to play basketball."

Your TL:

> "Do you really need a reason to play basket?"

Both look "okay".

To me as a native speaker, however, the nuance of the sentence-ender 「かね」 is considerably more important for a deeper comprehension of this sentence than the meaning of 「Xがないとだめ」 because 「Xがないとだめ」 only has one simple meaning with no hidden nuance -- "***if there is no X, it is no good***".

「かね」 makes the sentence a mixture of statement and question.  It implicitly asks for the listener's opinion (or at least a reaction) while making a statement with a hint of uncertainty held by the speaker regarding the content of the sentence prior to the final 「かね」.

In other words, it is not easy translating sentences ending with 「かね」.  One would need to "borrow" some words that are not used in the original sentence.

My own TL:

> "I wonder if you actually have got to have a reason to play basketball.  Whatcha think?"

Comment: Thanks, I updated the title to reflect your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I think the meaning of this sentence is 
“you must have a reason in order to play basket”
I heard from some animes and from the Japaneses, they end the sentence with “ですかね” with an affirmation meaning.